# Ubuntu install apache2 no httpd.conf

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I was following [this tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide) to install apache2 with mod_wsgi. When I came to the step `Loading Module Into Apache`, I need to edit the `httpd.conf` file to load modules. However, there is no such file in `/etc/apache2`.

The file structure of /etc/apache2 is as follows:

```
apache2.conf
conf-available/
conf-enabled/
envvars
magic
mods-available/
mods-enabled/
ports.conf
sites-available/
sites-enabled/
```

Did I miss anything? Or what should I do then?

Comment: Add the module to apache2.conf file

Comment: Linux distributions use their own unique layout for Apache and do not follow the standard Apache Software Foundation layout. You should therefore refer to your Linux specific documentation on how to enable the mod_wsgi module and not use the mod_wsgi documentation for that. Depending on what you are doing, you may find it easier initially to use mod_wsgi express. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Answer (score 1):

Configuration file is no longer included. If you have the Apache sources available, you have the sample file in `docs/conf/httpd.conf`. Copy it to `/etc/apache2` or `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` (depending on the distribution).